# Rewire EZ VINYL/TAPE CONVERTER to protools

Tags: converter, pro-tools, recording, plugin

Hi guys I recently got EZ a VINYL/TAPE CONVERTER, I will use it to convert/capture/record a load of old vinyls from my late father's massive collection. I tried running the program with protools simultaneously in the hopes that it would come up as an instrument like melodyne etc. But it doesn't. The EZ audio converter program itself is frustrating to see the least, it has minimal functionality when it comes to setting the bit depth or sample rate. I have to set that up in itunes but itunes doesnt have a 24 bit option and even if it did (hypothetical=I havent tried yet) the amount of control I actually have over the recording is so limited.

I would like to know if there is a rewire plugin or something I can download to set EZ VINYL/TAPE CONVERTER as a client in protools?

Answer (score 2):

If you have ProTools (and understandably a hardware unit to plug into), why not just feed in the RCAs, create a 96k/24bit session, create an Aux and an Audio Track, bus them so that they feed from the Aux to the Audio Track, record to the track (using the Aux beforehand to set your input level).  Do any RTAS EQ or limiting afterward, then bounce to 320kbps MP3 (if thats what you need instead of wav) at 44.1k, 16 bit.  Whenever I've digitized vinyl that's what I've done.

Comment: I will def try that


Comment: Can't send the output of a turntable to PT without a phono preamp first. The RIAA curve is set by the pre and wax.

Turntable -> Phono Preamp -> RCA out of amp -> Pro Tools Interface.

No limiting and processing as it's already mastered. Maybe some later if needed. Go in at 44.1kHz and 16 bit.

You can use strip silence later to break long track into smaller ones

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware of that, although thank you for mentioning it so that it ties into the how signal flow should be.  The way that the question was stated implied, to me, that this basic knowledge about a turntable was already understood, although it's possible that the answer they didn't already know this.  It also depends upon the turntable model too, as the Numark TTX has a built-in preamp.